# Возможно ли избежать дублирование интерфейсов WCF-сервера в WCF-клиенте?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Начал недавно разбираться с WCF и задался вопросом - можно ли как-то избежать копипаста интерфейсов из solution сервера в solution клиента?

Comment: Вынести в сборку и переиспользовать её?

Comment: оформить интерфейсы отдельным проектом и положить ссылку на него с сервера и с клиента?

Comment: Какой ещё копипаст? Откуда он возьмётся? Классы/интерфейсы на клиенте генерируются автоматически на основании схемы wsdl. И вообще, сервер пишется на одном языке, совершенно независимо от клиентов. А клиенты могут быть написаны на совсем других языках, другими людьми, у которых нет доступа к коду сервера.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov копипаст там есть, когда клиент и сервер пишутся на одном языке одними и теми же людьми. tym32167 и Monk правы, это решается выносом контрактов в отдельный проект. Постоянно обновлять сгенерированный по wsdl код, лично мне не понравилось, проще вынести и мусора в коде меньше. А для сторонних клиентов генерация по wsdl на любом языке, тут вы абсолютно правы.